# Credentials in Managed Packages for HTTP Callouts

Tags: managed-package, callout

What is the best practice to make an authorised HTTP(s) callout from a Managed Package, i.e. how to handle the credentials safely? So my managed package should call an external webservice, which requires credentials for authentication.

I would expect the following from the solution:

- store credentials in the target org safely
- users in the target org have no access to the credentials
- ISV has the ability to change the credentials when necessary

Is this possible?

Comment: Look into using [protected custom metadata types](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/custom_metadata_types_adv/cmt_manageability) to store credentials. It'll expose them internally to your package and can be hidden from the subscribing orgs.